# Disabling P4V progress bar when submit fails

Tags: perforce, p4v

I'm developing a trigger script for Perforce. I can install it and it works fine. One thing that bugs me is whenever a commit fails in P4V, there are 2 windows that open in this GUI. One is "P4V" and after some time "Submit Changelist Progress" bar opens.

This is rather inconvenient since the failure message is in "P4V" window, but while reading the message "Submit Changelist Progress" bar shows up and blocks it. Also there's no way to hide the "Submit Changelist Progress" bar without closing "P4V" window (this involves carefully dragging "P4V" window everytime this error occurs). I really thing the "Submit Changelist Progress" bar is redundant, this progress bar also never updates. Is there a way to disable this?

Regards,
An Overflower[image]

Comment: Does this still occur with the most recent version of P4V? If so, drop an email to Perforce Technical Support and let them know so they can fix it.